# Forecast Vs Actual accuracy calculation

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have two time series, first is forecasted values (results of some forecasting algorithm) and second series is, actual values observed for same time frame.

We are trying to compare both these series and find out how much forecasted values are inline with actual values. We have used [MAPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) & [MAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) formulas which are fine when the difference between both are small values.

When difference between actual and forecast values are far off, MAE and MAPE are bigger values (I understand that MAPE has no upper limit, which is why bigger values).

These values make sense for statistician, but when common users saw these numbers,  feedback we got was our accuracy calculation is doomed. Now the task we are trying to answer is, how can we calculate the difference between forecast vs actual (using MAE (or) MAPE (or) some other algorithm) and show it with in range of `0 - 100%`?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** These numbers are handmade to convey the problem we are trying to solve, please don't consider about what forecasting algorithm may improve our forecast values etc., irrespective what best algorithm we use, there are few data sets we have could force us into this particular situation.

Here is example time series:

[image]

Comment: If we just look at the 9 observations you listed, your forecast is indeed poor, and a naive model would work better.  But there may be a lot more to the series we're not seeing -- for example, these may be off-season forecasts, where the mean forecast and actual may both be, say, 2000.  How do you subjectively feel about the quality of these forecasts?

Comment: @zbicyclist: 1) Those numbers are hand made numbers, our original timeseries has lot more points 2) We understand that our forecast is indeed poor in this case and would like to show something like 1% (or) 2% (or) 5% accurate comparing with actual values, instead of showing 499% error, which for common users look strange. This way our users knows they can ignore this forecast because it has very low accuracy and feed data set to us to improve our implementation.

Comment: @zbicyclist: I understand your concern and I am aware that there are seasonality, trend factors which influence forecast. Assume those are all factored in and our algorithm (as you know one algorithm doesn't fit all data sets and unfortunately we are in that space), but produced bad forecast for this data set, how can we show some number between 0 - 100 instead of showing some number like 499, that is the point we are struggling at this moment.

Comment: Most forecasts are procedures that begin with fitting a model in a way that minimizes some measure of accuracy. You should prefer to use the same measure in assessing the quality of the forecast!

Comment: The best way is to compute the cost of forecast errors in units that business users understand. For instance, if it's sales forecast, then there could be a cost associated with error in dollars. The cost is usually asymmetric, btw.

Comment: @Aksakal: That is nice suggestion, but we want to show accuracy rather than error. In general when we show accuracy, it falls between 0-100% right? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Nambari, let's say actual is \$100, and your forecast was \$500. What is the accuracy in your understanding?

Comment: @Aksakal: For your example our forecast is no way reliable. Accuracy of the forecast value is ZERO (or) near ZERO percent. That is what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Nambari, it's not common to think in terms of accuracy where precise forecast is 100% and bad forecast is 0%. I think this is your issue with applying MAPE, you're not using it conventionally.

Comment: @Aksakal: If you don't mind, could you please elaborate little bit more on your previous comment?

Comment: @Nambari, in my example the conventional understanding would be that my \$500 forecast was $\frac{500-100}{100}*100\%=400\%$ error, not 0% accuracy as you suggested. Also, be careful with using [*accuracy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) term, it's usually reserved for a bias, and *precision* is often used for error variance. When we compute MAPE we sort of combine them in one error measure.

Comment: @Aksakal: Thanks! now I got what you mean by conventional understanding. In our case we are biased to show that our forecasts are good (for most of the cases), which is the reason why picked term accuracy. I think you almost got where we are struggling, in business most of the times app want to show we are x% of good rather than 400% bad, which is why we are leaning towards converting this error percentage to success percentage (in this case success % will be lower number). Any thoughts? Your comments helped lot, thanks!

Comment: @Nambari, stick to what's conventional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach I've used for this problem is to define the MAPE as

(A-F)/(average of A and F)

instead of

(A-F)/A.

This measure (which I think I borrowed from Mosteller and Tukey's book, but I don't have it at hand right now) is symmetric and bounded by -200% and +200%.  I know you wanted it to be 0 through 100, but I got you partway there with a measure I may be able to find a reference for.

I have used this where (a) I wanted a symmetric measure, and (b) where I wanted to cap the errors ['whether they were horrible (200%) or atrocious (5000%) didn't matter].  The image below compares a standard MAPE with this calculation (AdjMAPE). Later edit: because the errors are signed, they should be a form of MPE, not MAPE. See also comments below by me and whuber.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, I think the approach you followed here is similar to sMAPE referred here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error (but this seems not a real absolute percentage accuracy calculation based Rob J because results are in negative accuracy) https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5

Comment: Many analytical laboratories call this figure the "Relative Percent Difference": see (Google books) at https://books.google.com/books?id=XMW6JsJrLK4C&pg=PA168&dq=relative+percent+difference+laboratory+quality&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uveZVOrsMMX_gwSktIDIDA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=relative%20percent%20difference%20laboratory%20quality&f=false or https://books.google.com/books?id=-4n-2q627ZgC&pg=PA24&dq=relative+percent+difference+laboratory+quality&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uveZVOrsMMX_gwSktIDIDA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=relative%20percent%20difference%20laboratory%20quality&f=false, for instance.

Comment: @whuber when you say this figure, you mean -200 to 200 (or) 0 to 100%? Will go through the links you posted, thanks for your time!

Comment: It's precisely the formula given in this answer: the difference divided by the average.  It's a measure that is appropriate when *both* quantities are subject to random error (of approximately the same magnitude). It tends to be near $0$ and in size much less than $100\%$, making it readily interpretable (that's one reason labs use it).  Remember, it's measuring an *error*, so zero is best. RPDs of size greater than $100\%$ are usually considered pretty bad.

Comment: Yes, in looking for a reference I see Hyndman and Athanasopoulos define sMAPE similarly (page 46) except that in my formula the errors are signed, and in their formula they are absolute. https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5

Comment: One would use absolute errors as an objective function for optimization, but signed errors to assess the associated residuals.  Compare this with $\chi^2$ residuals in analyzing a two-way table, for instance: the $\chi^2$ statistic is a sum of non-negative terms $(O-E)^2/E$, but the residuals $(O-E)\sqrt{E}$ are given the signs of the differences $O-E$ so you can see which data are higher than expected and which are lower.

Comment: Thank you both! let me read through these links tonight. If anyone has any other thoughts, please do post.